# Why would you install node using bower

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

Ok it may sound like a stupid question.

But I was wondering, why would one install node using `bower`. I mean `bower` already requires `nodejs` and `npm` as clearly stated on their [website](http://bower.io/#installing-bower), right?

---

Will try to make it more clear by adding what I added as comment below:

I mean `bower` already need `node` and `npm`, then why would someone use `bower` to install `node` again? What's the point? Is there any specific use case? I cant think of any though!

Comment: or maybe I am drunk? :P

Comment: ok maybe i am missing something, but I think this is really stupid. The only use-case I could think of is to install `node` as a local package limited to the application folder you are working on. But till it doesn't make sense. `Node` is still installed on your system. Maybe u can use it to install a different versions maybe? I am going mad!

Comment: why would someone downvote this ques?

Comment: @NeerajKumar I didn't downvote, but someone may have downvoted because the question is a little unclear. You ask why someone would use `bower` to install `node`, but the question assumes someone has actually done this. Do you have any examples of this happening?

Comment: Hi Micheal,
Basically you can apparently install `node` using `bower`. My question is why would someone do that? what's the benefit?

checkout the example here.http://pastebin.com/TyTQMhi1

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but it seems like you are confused on something there.

[npm](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) or `Node Package Manager` it is use for installing/managing the `node modules` **server sides**

Usage example: `npm install express` or `npm install bower -g`

Whereas [bower](http://bower.io) you use that to install anything that is use **client-side**

Usage example: `bower install jquery` or `bower install font-awesome`

---

Ignore my above answer if you are talking about why there is a package on the bower component for `node`.

If so I think they've registered that in bower but not even sure what can you really do with that since most of the stuff would require you to run it server-side, but some library maybe accessible/usable client-side. I have to search/find the example from that to demonstrate but I couldn't find one at the moment.

Comment: `$ bower search node`, try it ;)

Comment: Yeah @robertklep I saw that too :P but what can you do with that on the client-side? :P

Comment: Nothing obviously, but you *can* install Node using Bower apparently :)

Comment: Your second answer is what I am talking about. I mean `bower` already need `node` and `npm`, then why would someone use `bower` to install `node` again? What's the point? Is there any specific use case? I cant think of any though!

Comment: npm is perfectly valid for client-side use